# I have to get a large number of photos approved for my project. Is there an online tool or platform that can help me with this?

Tags: images, software-recommendation, tools, photography

We've had a photographer do a three day shoot to provide imagery for the project I'm working on. From the thousands of shots she took we want to get down to an initial set of 75 images that have been approved by the client for use on the site we've designed.

At the moment I'm primarily using a Bridge to make my choices, then InDesign to put these into documents to share with the client as PDFs. They then comment on the PDF and send it back. I then manually make changes to the documents to reflect the feedback.

It all feels very cumbersome and inefficient.

Is there a tool that you have used that would help in this instance? Something that will show a large number of images and keep track of their status (i.e. new, approved, rejected, not sure). Ideally it would also allow me to attribute bits of meta data to images (e.g. The name of the article that this image may be used for, or tags describing the section of the site it would appear on).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will be good enough to handle that huge quantity of pictures, but it's a very nice collaborative tool for designers and get comments on pictures.

I like to use [HightailSpaces](https://hightailspaces.com) for that kind of thing.

You can create "Space" that are like folders that you share with your client, and upload your pictures there.

On each Space, you can have a revision number, share it, protect it with password or not, and invite people to comment.

You and your client can click on the image to add comments on precise areas of the picture, and you can discuss about it. It's easy to follow what's going on and you get an email for each comment. You can delete and add pictures as you want.

It,s still new and beta but it's from a well established company that was known as "yousendit"; they're still working on improving that service.

**Here's a screenshot of a "Space":**

[image: Hightail Space Picture Gallery]

**Here's a screenshot of one picture:**

When you click on the picture, it adds a comment with your avatar and name. And the conversation goes on the side.

[image: Hightail detailed picture and discussion]

**This is when you want to add versions, if you need to compare them:**

You can add pictures with a drag and drop or the uploader.

[image: drag and drop upload]

The way I could see it work with your project is that you could upload all the picture and delete the ones that get rejected. And go by elimination this way. The client can download all the pictures at once or simply use that working space for his/her comments. So instead of tagging in bridge and uploading/downloading every time, they could stay online.

And for the "favorite ones" they could go in another "Space" that will be sorted as well as better pictures get added to it.

Now frankly I don't know if it can handle 1000 images, I guess you'll need to try. I think they have a trial and the subscription is very cheap. I don't think your client needs to pay for a subscription, but they do need an account.

Comment: That sounds pretty good! I'll take a look. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I use Dropbox for these situations. I upload, for example 500 images in new folder, then share it with my client and then he adds comments on each image, pretty much the same idea as already in first answer, but take a look, maybe helps: [Dropbox - manage files](https://www.dropbox.com/guide/business/manage-files/comments)

Comment: That sounds like a really simple way to do it! Thanks